ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
This is my libraries
import yfinance as yf from causalimpact  
import CausalImpact  
import pandas as pd  
import seaborn as sns  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

I get an error at the from causalimpact import CausalImpact
as

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed


Hi@project work,There is some issue with installed tensorflow or the version mismatch with the python version. Please refer to this link to install tensorflow as per your system OS with the correct TF build configuration and also check causalimpact package
